# c# Entity Framework navigation problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i've a doubt on navigation property in EF4 Model designer.

Let's suppose we have two Entities: Hotel - Country.

If I design an 1:1 association between them, the designer add two navigation properties for each entity. One of them is in the Hotel (named Country), the second one is in the Country (named Hotel).

Now, if i reason on it, i can say that the Hotel navigation property in the Country entity is unuseful.
Can i delete it? Why does Entity Framework designer add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say Hotel-Country should be a many-to-one relationship, no? Country can have many Hotels.

However, to answer the question: yes, you can simply delete navigation properties (you can also turn it off when creating the association in the designer). The designer adds it 'by default'.

Comment: ya, you're right. It should be 1:N .. anyway, if i delete the navigation property, does it imply a performance improvement?

Comment: No, the presence of the navigation property has no effect in itself. Navigation properties for collections can have an impact on performance if not used wisely (e.g. SELECT N + 1 problems when using lazy loading) .